# How does a custom sorting function work for multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have combed the web to try and give myself some understanding as to what the following means as it pertains to the object below. What does "a" and "b" mean? Why is it significant?

```
students.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.fn-b.ln
})

var students = [{
    fn : "Stone",
    ln : "Carpenter",
    scores : [61,99,73,68,80,62,176,78]
},
{
    fn : "Samson",
    ln : "Sears",
    scores : [68,193,91,190,95,65,171,75]
},
{
    fn : "Quin",
    ln : "Morton",
    scores : [79,95,161,92,182,163,198,182]
},
{
    fn : "Qunitessa",
    ln : "Hardy",
    scores : [99,65,75,69,77,67,86,78]
},
{
    fn : "Ashley",
    ln : "England",
    scores : [147,70,81,64,148,71,70,63]
},
{
    fn : "Thaddeus",
    ln : "Hutchinson",
    scores : [99,190,188,185,160,88,89,76]
},
{
    fn : "Yeo",
    ln : "Hayes",
    scores : [88,64,199,165,198,76,74,81]
},
{
    fn : "Rylee",
    ln : "Larson",
    scores : [71,126,63,71,168,173,175,88]
}
];
```

I understand that the anonymous function will return a value of -1,0,1, but what is the significance of the arguments `a` and `b` since I will not be passing any values (such as `employees.sort(a.something, b.something)`) when I call the function. With the above data I need to sort by clicking on one of the headers of my table -- which will involve sorting string and number values. Any ideas as to how to sort the nested values in the "scores" array? How would I go about sorting via the first/last name?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort . "a" and "b" refer to elements of some sortable pair. The sort algo uses this rule for each item in your array.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` method of an Array will take your sorting function and apply it when necessary to compare two elements and determining their sort order. `a` and `b` will be two elements of the Array you are sorting.

To sort your objects alphabetically by last name, you will need a sorting function like this one:

```
function lastNameCompare(a, b) {
    var sortFieldA = a.ln.toLowerCase();
    var sortFieldB = b.ln.toLowerCase();
    return sortFieldA == sortFieldB ? 0 : (sortFieldA < sortFieldB ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Remove the `.toLowerCase()` if you want your sort to be case sensitive. To sort for something like "*last name, first name*" you would use the following lines instead:

```
    var sortFieldA = (a.ln + ", " + a.fn).toLowerCase();
    var sortFieldB = (b.ln + ", " + b.fn).toLowerCase();
```

To also sort the scores in your data you will need to perform a sort on every entry of your data set:

```
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    var student = students[i];
    student.scores.sort();
}
```

Note that you don't need an explicit sorting function in this case, since `sort` will use numeric sort order by default.

Comment: Your awesome, but where does the function get the elements to determine their sort order if I am not passing the elements as parameters? Or am I?

Comment: You are calling the `sort` method explicitly on your Array, `students.sort(...)`, and pass it your sorting function. The `sort` method of the Array then takes your function and applies it to its elements where necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much. What I am doing is creating a dynamic TABLE and I need the ability to sort via the table headers. I am having a difficult time sorting the data in the nested array. I want to sort the array by the nested first value, nested second value etc ... any ideas?

    scores : [99,190,188,185,160,88,89,76]
99 would be the first column, 190 would be the second column and so forth ...

Comment: You should probably write another question with more details and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

`.sort` takes a callback. It will then pick two elements from the array and pass them to the callback function. The callback function returns which element is greater. `.sort` rearranges the two elements in the array based on that information. It then takes two other elements and passes them into the callback. Rinse, repeat until the array is sorted.

`a` and `b` are simply the variables for "an element" and "another element". Call them whatever you like. There's no significance to the naming.